# How to enable tap to click option on trackpad when mouse and trackpad settings are minimal?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

By minimal (or less setting options), I mean this:

[18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sEqM.png)

This seems wrong because in earlier versions (for e.g. 13.04) it's like this:

[13.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/raring-mouse-settings.jpg)

Is this a driver issue? or just that they have reduced the options? and if so, how can I enable the tap to click option?

Thanks

Comment: what is your desktop environment?

Comment: It's was unity and not gnome. I changed it back in 17.10 and then upgraded my distribution.

Comment: Have you not tried from gnome tweaks?

Comment: I'll check it out.